# How to auto sum by date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large data base of information pretraining to employees' productivity.  Simply put on a give day an employee will perform a reparative task in multiple locations.  In the data base the employees' name, and date, number of items made and many other bits of data (that i don't care about)  are recorded.  I can not change how this is entered, I just need to pull out, and sum up, how many items each person made each day-- Ultimately I want to know the average items made by each person each day.

How can I generate a table with the totals from all the cells for each date?

This is an example of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if We suppose that your table is "Productivity" and columns are Date, EmployeeName, NumOfItems, others

In Excel you need to

1. Select the table data including headers
2. go to Menu Insert -> PIvot Table ->OK
3. Generate the pivot table as follow:
   [In Rows include date, in Columns Employee, in Values NumofItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mneg.png)
4. You have your required sum of items per date per employee

if you have source data in any Database in SQL
you can also make the query using group:

SELECT date, EmployeeName, SUM(NumofItems) FROM Productivity GROUP BY date, EmployeeName